# Customizing Wordpress (Genesis) Child Theme

Tags: html, css

I do write a blog and content on it, but I am facing an appearance issue.
Currently I use Genesis framework and News-Pro theme. But the problem is that it doesn't look right. How do I change its design to Full Width Size view.

My blog is [www.promocodeadda.com](http://www.promocodeadda.com)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit your style.css. Remove max-width from .site-container-wrap (line number 582)

Answer (score -1):

If you change the max width it will de displayed in the full width of your browser...

You will find it in:

style.css > on line 582 .site-container-wrap